# How to fetch new AWS key on new file upload in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, coffeescript

Upon a new file upload, I want the new Key for the selected file. How to do this in Rails using jQuery?

HTML -

```
<div id="target" data-key="<%= @aws_url[:key] if !@aws_url.nil? %>">
   <% if !@aws_url.nil? %>
    <img id="user" src="<%= @aws_url[:url] %>">
   <% end %>
</div>

<form id="user_form" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="user_key" value="<%= @aws_urls[0][:key] %>"/>
   <input id="file_upload" type="file" accept="image/*" name="user_id"/>
</form>
```

Upon user selecting a new file every time, a new key should be assigned to **@aws_url[:key]** how can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? I don't think I get it.

Comment: @qcam When a user upload's a new file, the AWS key value should be reset. This is what I need!

Comment: I'm still puzzled but if you want to get the value of `data-key`, you can `$("#target").data("key")`

Comment: I've the value of the data-key but I want it to get a new value when a file upload happens by the user.
How do I get the new value for data-key on a successful file change in the input! @qcam